# Wrong amount, getting less output then input in rolls

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a die calculator for math class and when I use an amount n=1000 it get a result that is lower (around approx 800). It worked earlier. The frequency seems to be fine sometimes, but its the amount of rolls that don't add up. Can anyone help me out finding the error?

This is my Python code:

```
    from ast import operator
    from itertools import count
    from os import sep
    from random import randint
    import random

    rolled = []
    rolledtimes = 0;

    def roll():
        rand = randint(1, 7)
        return rand

    ROLLED = {i: 0 for i in range(1, 7)}
    n = int(input("How many rolls?"))

    def probability():
        print("Frequency")
        for key, count in ROLLED.items():
            print("\t{}: {:.2f}".format(key, count*100./n*1))

    for _ in range(n):
        ROLLED[random.randint(1, 6)] += 1

    rolled = [roll() for __ in range(n)]
    count = [rolled.count(i) for i in range(1, 7)]
    print('Rolled {} times:\n\n1 is rolled {} times \n2 is rolled {} times \n3 is rolled {} times \n4 is rolled {} times \n5 is rolled {} times \n6 is rolled {} times\n'format(rolledtimes,count[0],count[1],count[2],count[3],count[4],count[5]))

    probability()
```

Comment: You're printing the counts for 1-6, but the `roll` function is returning 1-7.  The missing counts are the times it came up 7.

Comment: And why are you repeating the rolls when you already have `ROLLED`?

Comment: Thank you! Did not se that it was returning 1-7 for some needed 1-7 or else it just locked up. And the repeating rolls were just a demo code i forgot to remove after some tinkering from before  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is randint, you select randomly a number between 1 and 7 (both included) but when you count this numbers,  you count only the number  between 1-6, therefore you  get 8.. counts.

```
from ast import operator
from itertools import count
from os import sep
from random import randint
import random

rolled = []
rolledtimes = 0;

def roll():
    rand = randint(1, 7)
    return rand

ROLLED = {i: 0 for i in range(1, 7)}
n = int(input("How many rolls?"))

def probability():
    print("Frequency")
    for key, count in ROLLED.items():
        print("\t{}: {:.2f}".format(key, count*100./n*1))

for _ in range(n):
    ROLLED[random.randint(1, 6)] += 1

rolled = [roll() for __ in range(n)]
print(len(rolled))
count = [rolled.count(i) for i in range(1, 8)]
print('Rolled {} times:\n\n1 is rolled {} times \n2 is rolled {} times \n3 is rolled {} times \n4 is rolled {} times \n5 is rolled {} times \n6 is rolled {} times\n7  is rolled {} times\n'.format(rolledtimes,count[0],count[1],count[2],count[3],count[4],count[5],count[6]))
probability()
```

my results:

```
1 is rolled 137 times 
2 is rolled 150 times 
3 is rolled 125 times 
4 is rolled 147 times 
5 is rolled 146 times 
6 is rolled 133 times
7  is rolled 162 times
Total count: 1000
enter code here
```